# O que um diagrama de classes contém?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, classes, diagrama

O título é uma pergunta meio estúpida, pois o nome do diagrama já responde. Mas ontem essa pergunta me surgiu a cabeça quando um professor de Análise e Projetos de Software pediu a toda turma o diagrama de classes do que seria nosso projeto para conclusão do período.

Até ai tudo bem, seria só mais um na infinidade de diagramas que fazemos nas faculdades hoje, e então ele fez uma colocação um tanto quanto impossível de ser realizada ao menos de minha parte. Segundo ele o nosso diagrama de classes deverá conter além das classes básicas também as regras de negócio, interfaces, fachadas, classes DAO, e o principal meus *controllers* (sistema é web e desenvolvido com JSF, seria o Bean).

Isso está certo? digo, não é comum vermos um diagrama assim, isso realmente existe?

Comment: Perceba que eu editei o título da sua pergunta novamente. Você pode entender melhor em [“\[Resolvido\]” em título de pergunta não fica parecendo coisa de fórum?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5389/18246)

Comment: Obrigado jbueno, algumas pessoas já pediram para min fazer isso então colocava achando que era o certo!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Na verdade creio que dependa.
Existem diversos tipos de diagrama de classe.

**Conceitual :**

Representa de uma forma um pouco mais abstrata, não necessariamente fazendo referência a implementação final.

Exemplo:

[image: Diagrama Conceitual]

**Especificação:**
Perspectiva voltada para aqueles que precisam saber as regras do sistema mas não sua implementação (como gerente de projetos por exemplo)
Por isso tem foco nos principais métodos do sistema.

Exemplo:

[image: Diagrama de especificação]

**Implementação (O mais utilizado, e provavelmente o que o seu professor quer):**
Possuí todas as classes do sistema e seus métodos, atributos, interfaces e tudo que for relacionado a implementação.
Voltado ao time de desenvolvimento, com todos os detalhes necessários para a implementação do sistema.

Exemplo:

[image: Diagrama de implementação:]

Isso não significa que caso haja a necessidade, esses diagramas não possam ser alterados para comportar um novo método ou classe que inicialmente não foi especificada.

Refer~encia: http://www.dsc.ufcg.edu.br/~jacques/cursos/map/html/uml/diagramas/classes/classes1.htm

Comment: Obrigado Lucas, achei que meu professor estava meio maluco, mas vou ter que estudar bastante isso pois o que é passado é muito diferente do que ele pediu. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Normalmente o diagrama de classes é uma das últimas etapas do processo, depois de ter feito os outros diagramas como caso de uso, relacionamentos, etc...

Comment: Porém, acho importante salientar que com a popularização do desenvolvimento Ágil, está sendo bem raro encontrar um projeto com o UML completo, diagrama de classes então, particularmente participei de pouquíssimos projetos com um.

Answer (score 4):

O diagrama de classes lista os conceitos que serão implementados no sistemas e as suas relações. Ele é consequência do levantamento de requisitos, definição de casos de usos e classes. A grande importância do diagrama é que ele define a estrutura do sistema.

Esse exemplo, retirado do site do [Macoratti](http://www.macoratti.net/net_uml1.htm), mostram as etapas básicas envolvidas na criação do diagrama:

> - Levantamento e análise de requisitos do sistema a ser desenvolvido. Entrevista com o dentista(s) e com as pessoas que trabalham no
>     consultório
> - Definição dos objetos do sistema : Paciente, agenda, dentista, serviço, contrato, consulta, pagamento, etc..
> - Definição dos atores do sistema : paciente, dentista , secretária
> - Definição e detalhamento dos casos de uso: marcar consulta , confirmar consulta , cadastrar paciente , cadastrar serviços , etc.
> - Definição das classes :  paciente , dentista , exame , agenda , serviço
> - Definir os atributos e métodos das classes :
>
> Após toda esta análise você chega  no diagrama de classes do sistema:
>   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você pode ler mais sobre diagramas de classes:

- [UML: Diagrama de Classes](http://www.devmedia.com.br/artigo-sql-magazine-63-utilizando-uml-diagrama-de-classes/12251)
- [Diagrama de Classes](http://www.dsc.ufcg.edu.br/~jacques/cursos/map/html/uml/diagramas/classes/classes1.htm)
- [UML - Diagrama de Classes e objetos](http://www.macoratti.net/net_uml1.htm)
- [Diagramas de classe UML: referência](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd409437.aspx)
- [Diagrama de Classes](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagrama_de_classes)

Comment: Tais, esse que você me passou como exemplo pra min é o comum, mas nunca soube que regras de negócios, as classes do DAO e até mesmo os controlladores do site serão inclusos em um diagrama.

Comment: E por isso meu espanto, até então isso para min seria algo impossível, pois nunca vi algo assim em nenhum lugar.

Comment: @user58589, os diagramas são usados para representar os sistemas, isso facilita a compreensão deles, ou seja, você consegue representar "todo" o seu sistema por eles.  Nesses links que eu eu deixei para complementar explica a parte teórica, como você está estudando vale a pena ler.

Comment: Tudo bem, vou olhar sim, obrigado pela ajuda!